# Use sys/socket.h in Eclipse working on Windows

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, sockets, android-ndk

I want to use Linux socket functions in a development board working in android. I have installed Eclipse on Windows to develop codes. I am going to use Android-NDK tool to use socket.h for android to be recognized. So my computer is not Linux, can i build my code on Windows?

Comment: That sounds like fairly ordinary usage of the Android NDK, which is a suite of cross compilers for building android binaries on Linux, OSX, or even Windows.  It should come with the necessary header files and include paths automatically set up if you invoke it in the intended way via the ndk-built script (bat file in your case?).  It would be a good idea to build and understand the hello-jni project from the samples directory before writing your own code.